# Does Enduro make a ceramic hybrid wheel bearing kit for WTB Laser Disc Lite hubs?

Tags: hub, bearings, ceramic

I would like to replace the bearings in my front and rear `WTB Laser Disc Lite` hubs. I'm interested in upgrading the OEM steel bearings to a ceramic hybrid. I've hear that Enduro is a quality manufacturer of ceramic hybrid bearings.

So, does Enduro make a ceramic hybrid bearing replacement kit for `WTB Laser Disc Lite` hubs?

I was unable to find any information on Enduro's site (http://www.endurobearings.com) or on other sites selling Enduro wheel bearing kits.

Please provide information on part numbers and where to buy.

Comment: As it is, the question is somewhat esoteric unless a user is familiar with bearings. Also, you're you're just asking for a product link, something that could probably be resolved by calling the manufacturer. Perhaps you could give more information about the problem, outlining what you need the bearing replacements for? You *may* get more responses that way.

Comment: @neilfein: I need to replace the bearings in my front hub. I've heard that Enduro manufactures quality replacement bearings for hubs and bottom brackets which I why I'm interested it them specifically. Enduro doesn't mention anything specific to WTB Laser Disc Lite hubs on their site. Yes, I could contact the manufacture but then this information wouldn't be available to other people who have the same question. Isn't that the purpose of a stack exchange site: to be a Q&A database?

Comment: Correct, and now even more info is available. Thanks for expanding on the question.

Comment: @neilfein: I updated the question with more info. Thanks for the suggestion. Also, in the future please provide a link to an FAQ on what questions are appropriate and what makes a good question. I couldn't find one after a quick search on the meta site. That will help other newbies understand your critique.

Comment: That's certainly a fair request! The closest we have right now is the site FAQ, theres a link at the top of every page. That'll help you frame a question in the Stack Exchange way. We'll eventually put more detail in the main FAQ, but we're still working out the details in terms of what's on and off topic. There are a few threads on the meta.bicycles site; check out the ones with the tag [on-off-topic](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wtb.com/pdf/manuals/ServiceLDLiteV6.pdf

This service .pdf indicates that you need 15x26x7 bearings. I did a quick search on Enduros website and they don't appear to make this size in ceramic.

A quick web search came up with one option that I could (quickly) find.

http://www.vxb.com/page/bearings/PROD/Kit7872

Typically, in my experience, the bearing manufacturers are not going to say that they have a kit for a WTB LaserDisc Lite hub. They simply make bearings of a given size and if they are what you need, great.

What the .pdf doesn't specify is what size the freehub body bearings are. It gives a part number for replacement as a UNIT but does not break it down into its finer parts. Read further along in the .pdf and they do indicate that you can replace the bearings from the freehub quite easily. My recommendation is taking them out, measuring them w/ a vernier caliper and then doing a quick search to see if you can acquire a ceramic version.

Hopefully this helps a bit.